# Execute only on a certain page

Tags: php, functions, wp-enqueue-script

I"m trying to get the block of code below to load only when it's the contact page but it doesn't seem to wotk. Any ideas what the problem could be. Still pretty much new to PHP.

```
if (is_page('/contact-us/')) {
if ( function_exists( 'wpcf7_enqueue_scripts' ) ) {
        wpcf7_enqueue_scripts();
        wpcf7_enqueue_styles();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `contact-us` the correct page slug? Try without the slashes, i.e. `is_page('contact_us')`

Comment: Yes it is the correct one. It does work even without the slashes.

Comment: Is that really necessary? Isn't Contact Form 7 smart enough to only enqueue its scripts when needed already? (I don't know, I'd just be surprised if it wasn't.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) function accepts any of the page ID, the page title or the page slug. It looks like you're trying to give it an URL fragment instead.

You say that 'contact-us' is the page slug for your contact page, so try

```
if (is_page('contact-us')) {
```

without the forward slashes, i.e. passing the page slug, instead.